# General subject publishers of cheet-sheet-style reference material

Tags: resource-request, chinese, spanish, french, arabic

For the purpose of studying subjects of interest in target language(s), I want to discover any other publishers of cheat sheets or reference material similar to those in the links below; that is, overviews of key concepts, taxonomy, terminology, short descriptions, and labelled pictures.

https://www.barcharts.com/subjects/ 
https://www.barcharts.com/products/ 
https://permacharts.com

With regard to accepting an answer, publishers of material in non-English languages—in particular those which overlap the ones tagged in this post—are preferred.